# parsing and querying OWL-S profile.owl file using Jena-2.5.7

Tags: web-services, sparql, jena

I've problem with querying a service profile file `Profile.owl` using Jena on Eclipse,
I used the following query:

```java
String queryString = 
    "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
    + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "
    + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
    + "PREFIX service: <http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Service.owl#> "
    + "PREFIX profile: <http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Profile.owl#> "
    +"SELECT ?service ?y WHERE {  ?service <profile:profile> ?a ."
    +"?a <service:presentedBy> ?b ."
    +"?b <profile:serviceName> ?y .}";
```

A snippet of the service profile file look like this:

```xml
 <profile:Profile  rdf:ID="AddServiceName">
 <service:presentedBy rdf:resource="AddServicePresenter"/>
 <profile:serviceName>"ser"</profile:serviceName>
```

There were no results at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the data doesn't look quite like what your query expects it to look like.  Let's look at the graph described by this RDF/XML snippet:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://example.org/"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:service="http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Service.owl#"
         xmlns:profile="http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Profile.owl#">
 <profile:Profile  rdf:ID="AddServiceName">
   <service:presentedBy rdf:resource="AddServicePresenter"/>
   <profile:serviceName>"ser"</profile:serviceName>
 </profile:Profile>
</rdf:RDF>
```

in Turtle format, which is much closer to the pattern language of SPARQL:

```
@prefix service:  <http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Service.owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix profile:  <http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Profile.owl#> .

<http://example.org/#AddServiceName>
      a       profile:Profile ;
      profile:serviceName "\"ser\"" ;
      service:presentedBy <http://example.org/AddServicePresenter> .
```

In particular, note that an element in RDF/XML that corresponds to an subject or object in the RDF graph can use its XML element name as a shorthand for an `rdf:type` statement.  So `<profile:Profile rdf:ID="x">…</profile:Profile>` says that the resource `<...#x>` has `rdf:type profile:Profile`.  In Turtle and SPARQL, `a` is a shorthand for `rdf:type`, so `<...#x> a profile:Profile` means `<...#x> rdf:type profile:Profile`.  The other properties of `<...#x>` are determined by the content of the element.  In this case `<...#AddServiceName>` has two properties, one for `service:presentedBy` and one for `profile:serviceName`.

To find profiles, their presenters, and names, you need a query like:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX service: <http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Service.owl#> 
PREFIX profile: <http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.1/Profile.owl#> 

SELECT ?profile ?presenter ?name WHERE {
  ?profile a profile:Profile ;
           service:presentedBy ?presenter ;
           profile:serviceName ?name .
}
```

The triple pattern could also be written in a more verbose form:

```
?profile rdf:type profile:Profile .
?profile service:presentedBy ?presenter .
?profile profile:serviceName ?name .
```

Running this query produces these results:

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.rdf
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| profile                              | presenter                                | name      |
===============================================================================================
| <http://example.org/#AddServiceName> | <http://example.org/AddServicePresenter> | "\"ser\"" |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you a lot, but there is a problem in the syntax it may be related to the version of SPARQL or Jena or maybe both, the query didn't work.

Comment: Even "profile:servicename" didn't work so I had to write the entire URI instead, and it's quiet frustrating

Comment: @AousDeeb URIs are case sensitive, so `profile:serviceName` is a different URI than `profile:servicename`.

Comment: @AousDeeb I ran all the code that's in my answer through Jena/ARQ, and the results you're seeing there are what Jena produced.  What version of Jena and ARQ are you using, and can you show the input that you gave and the syntax error that you're getting?

Comment: You are right that was the issue Thanks a lot,
I have one more question, it's about editing the data in the triples (like the Object for a specific triple) is that possible in SPARQL supported in Jena-2.5.7 ? And is there an easier way to do so.

Comment: @AousDeeb If the answer worked for you, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to let others know that it works for you.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by editing the data in the triples; you can update the graph using SPARQL 1.1.  Jena 2.5.7 is a rather old version, you should consider updating to the 2.10.x series.  Comments aren't the place for this new question, though.  If you post it as another question it will get more attention than asking in the comments.

Comment: Jena 2.5.7 (Dec 2008) will have the original update language in the submission to W3C: http://www.w3.org/Submission/SPARQL-Update/ This is not SPARQL Update.  If at all possible, upgrade.